# Accepting command-line arguments for a chat-bot command

Tags: ruby, parameters

I'm kind of new on ruby, I got a Chat bot, with the original code from Sactage, https://github.com/sactage/chatbot-rb/tree/tweak-sql-performanc

I have a command that is for banning users, that works like:

```
!ban [username] [length in seconds] [reason]
```

In the `Client.rb` script its predefined:

```
 # Bans a user from chat. Requires mod rights (or above)
  # @param [String] user
  # @param [Fixnum] length
  # @param [String] reason
  def ban(user, length, reason)
    post(:msgType => :command, :command => :ban, :userToBan => user, :time => length, :reason => reason)
  end
```

and in "admin.rb" I got:

```
 # @param [User] user
 # @param [String] target
 # @param [Integer] length
 # @param [String] reason
def ban(user, target, length, reason)
  target.gsub!(/_/, ' ')
  if user.is? :mod
    @client.ban(target, length, reason)
    @client.send_msg "#{target} ha sido baneado gracias a la magia de la amistad."
  end
end
```

For it to work, but I'm working in something else, that automatically bans an user with certain trigger, so I can pre define the length and the Reason, so the user triggers it and it bans the user for the predefined time and reason, I got no idea how to do it, can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you give an example of a trigger?

Comment: It's not quite clear here what the problem is. Wouldn't you just call the `@client.ban` function with some arguments already filled in?

Comment: @JCM the trigger would be an inappropiate Link in the list, wait, I link a Github link of the plugins and the bot, I'm not really quite sure what am I doing to be honest :(  https://gist.github.com/carlosqh2/3fa24305356a8bb27349efa84f7e9323

Comment: @tadman Uh, its hilarious,  I'm not really sure how to do it... I'm really new in Ruby

Comment: It's not a Ruby thing per-se. If you have a method that does something, and it takes arguments, you must supply those arguments. You've sort of described your problem, but I'm not sure where the actual issue is.